# How to pass values from one component to other in React?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am displaying an employee table from the database. At the end of each record there is an "edit" link, on clicking that link I should be able to display a form below the table with the corresponding records in it. And I should be able to edit the records in the form and save it, the change should be reflected in the table.

Below, there is the "EmployeeRow" Component: where the rows are generated. In the `getInitialState` function the `showResult` is set as `false` (only on clicking the edit link, the showResult should be converted to true and the edit form should be displayed). In the `Editnavigate` function (which is triggered on clicking the edit link) the values of the record corresponding to the edit link are obtained and the `showResult` is set to `true` (so that the form can be displayed). In the `render` function the rows of the table with the employee records with edit link are generated.

```
var EmployeeRow = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
    return { showResults: false };
    },
    Editnavigate: function (e, id, fname,lname,gender,des,salary,city,country) {
        this.setState({ showResults: true });

    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.item.EmployeeID}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.FirstName}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.LastName}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.Gender}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.Designation}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.Salary}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.City}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.Country}</td>   
                  <td><a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.Editnavigate(e,this.props.item.EmployeeID,this.props.item.FirstName,this.props.item.LastName,this.props.item.Gender,this.props.item.Designation,this.props.item.Salary,this.props.item.City,this.props.item.Country)}>edit</a></td>               
              </tr>

            );
    }
});
```

Below, there is the EmployeeTable Component: where the data is obtained from the database and rendered, row part comes from the EmployeeRow component. Next to the table, the form has to be displayed on clicking edit link, for that I am using `{this.state.showResults ? <EmployeeForm /> : null }`. But I don't think this works as form is not getting displayed.

```
var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function(){

          return{
              result:[]
          }
      },
      componentWillMount: function(){

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
          xhr.onload = function () {
              var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

              this.setState({ result: response });

          }.bind(this);
          xhr.send();
      },
      render: function(){
          var rows = [];
          this.state.result.forEach(function (item) {
              rows.push(<EmployeeRow key={item.EmployeeID} item={item} />);
          });
          return (     <div>         
              <table className="table">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>EmployeeID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
             <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>

      <tbody>
          {rows}
      </tbody>

</table>
{this.state.showResults ? <Results /> : null }
</div>
 );
  }

  });
```

1) I need the form to be displayed on clicking the edit link.
2) The values of the corresponding record should be passed to the form on clicking edit.

Please let me know how to achieve this. Below, there is the displayed table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. There  is no `showResults` field in the local state for `EmployeeTable`. You have included it in `EmployeeRow`. 
   That won't help. Include  the  `showResults` in `EmployeeTable` state.
   Add one more prop to `EmployeeRow` `onEdit` - this is a function (`editNavigate`) defined in `EmployeeTable` which will be called when the user clicks on edit.
   `editNavigate` sets the `showResults` to true.
2. Add a field `editedRow` to the `EmployeeTable` component's state. Whenever a row is clicked, the `editedRow` will have the row detail. 
   While rendering the `Results`  component, pass the `editedRow` fields.

   ```
   <code>
   var EmployeeRow = React.createClass({
           getInitialState: function () {
               return {  };
           },
           Editnavigate: function (e,id,fname,lname,gender,des,salary,city,country) {
                   this.props.onEdit(e, id, fname,lname,gender,des,salary,city,country)
           },

           render: function () {
                   return (
                           <tr>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.EmployeeID}</td>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.FirstName}</td>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.LastName}</td>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.Gender}</td>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.Designation}</td>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.Salary}</td>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.City}</td>
                                       <td>{this.props.item.Country}</td>   
                                       <td><a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.Editnavigate(e,this.props.item.EmployeeID,this.props.item.FirstName,this.props.item.LastName,this.props.item.Gender,this.props.item.Designation,this.props.item.Salary,this.props.item.City,this.props.item.Country)}>edit</a></td>               
                               </tr>

                           );
           }
   });


   var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({

               getInitialState: function(){

                       return{
                               result:[],
                               showResults: false,
                               editedRow: {};
                       }
               },
               componentWillMount: function(){

                       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                       xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
                       xhr.onload = function () {
                               var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                               this.setState({ result: response });

                       }.bind(this);
                       xhr.send();
               },
               editNavigate = ({e, id, fname,lname,gender,des,salary,city,country}) => {
                   this.setState({ showResults: true, editedRow: { id, fname,lname,gender,des,salary,city,country } });
               };
               render: function(){
                       var rows = [];
                       this.state.result.forEach(function (item) {
                               rows.push(<EmployeeRow key={item.EmployeeID} item={item} onEdit={this.editNavigate} />);
                       });
                       return (     
                       <div>         
                               <table className="table">
                                     <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                   <th>EmployeeID</th>
                                                   <th>FirstName</th>
                                                   <th>LastName</th>
                                                   <th>Gender</th>
                                                   <th>Designation</th>
                                                   <th>Salary</th>
                                                   <th>City</th>
                                                   <th>Country</th>
                                                    <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                     </thead>

                                       <tbody>
                                               {rows}
                                       </tbody>

                               </table>
                       {this.state.showResults ? 
                               <Results 
                                   id={this.state.editedRow.id}
                                   fname={this.state.editedRow.fname}
                                   lname={this.state.editedRow.lname}
                                   gender={this.state.editedRow.gender}
                                   des={this.state.editedRow.des}
                                   salary={this.state.editedRow.salary}
                                   city={this.state.editedRow.city}
                                   country={this.state.editedRow.country}
                               /> 
                       : 
                       null 
                   }
                   </div>
                   );
               }
       });
   </code>
   ```

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you in resolving your problem?